# Integrate Facebook Workplace Account Login in own Page

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-workplace

i'm trying to let users on my site authenticate with their login details in my facebook workplace website. I think the SAML / SSO solution described in the documentation is not the thing im searching for.

Is there any thing like the normal "Login with Facebook" Button just for Workplace Accounts ?

It would be very nice if someone already touched this topic ;)

Greetings,
J. Doe ;)

Comment: No, it’s either SSO, or login via username/password, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/authentication/password

Comment: So, if i enable SSO login all actuall registred users will lost their acces to my portal right? Unless i add all accounts to my IAP's Database.. Is there no solution to only check if given email and password is right on a specific workplace instance?

Comment: Hi @J.Doe any news about it? Thanks!